# Change font size based on window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, fonts

Is it possible to change the CSS `font-size` and `line-height` of a headline based on the height of the browser window (not the width using media queries)?

Comment: Yes - use the `vh` unit - http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: **Self-shaming promotion:** I made a plugin for that kind of thing. You can take a look if it fit your needs. https://github.com/kagagnon/Responsive-Font

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Can I edit the line-height and letter spacing of the font with this method as well?

Comment: @BlakeBowman Unfortunately, not yet. It's something i'm gonna do one day, but alternatively, you can set a line-height as a percent of the font-size.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is. You can do this with CSS alone using [the `vh` (viewport height) unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#vh-unit):

> **vh unit**
>   Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block.

```
font-size: 1vh;     /* Equal to 1/100th of the viewport height. */
font-size: 50vh;    /* Equal to 1/2 of the viewport height. */
font-size: 100vh;   /* Equal to the viewport height. */
```

The same applies to `line-height`:

```
line-height: 1vh;     /* Equal to 1/100th of the viewport height. */
line-height: 50vh;    /* Equal to 1/2 of the viewport height. */
line-height: 100vh;   /* Equal to the viewport height. */
```

#### Demo

```css
html, body, h1 { margin: 0; }

h1 {
  font-size: 50vh;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

Comment: The original poster didn't specify the browser they were targeting, but this chart shows compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: @BlakeBowman you may also want to note the `vmin` unit. In the event the `height` is greater than the `width`, with `vh` alone our text may wrap onto multiple lines. `vmin` uses the smaller of the two dimensions. `1vmin` is equal to 1 100th of the size of the smallest of the two.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery:

```
$('#mySelector').css("font-size", $(window).height()/10);
```

demo with resize handling: http://jsfiddle.net/scu5Ltfh/